# Why do my comments keep disappearing in my asp.net aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing a webpage using visual studio 2013 and every time I make a comment in my code save it and then run it, my comments disappear.

Comment: What type of file are you updating, CSHTML, VBHTML, HTML, ASPX?

Comment: I am updating an aspx file

Comment: Could you ensure that other developers did not override the same file when they check-in?

Comment: I'm not using any source control, just a local project.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean your comments are dissapearing? In the actual .aspx page after the project builds ?

using <%-- comment goes here --%> will not be visible if you right click - view source.

try highlighting the code you want commented out and pressing CTRL + K,C to comment out code as well

Comment: The comments disappear in the actual code in the visual studio IDE

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will cause it's not an HTML element that will render in your web browser. What you have is a developer comment for you to see in design time but that will not render in page.

Most probably you have a comment like below

```
<%-- This is a comment --%>
```

Comment: it can't be. Are you sure you are viewing the same `.aspx` file and not a different one.

Comment: @user1314413 comments won't appear in the designer, only in the HTML window.  I never heard of anyone complaining of comments disappearing... I have used them myself without issue....

Comment: I am not sure whats going on, I think my visual studio is just bugging out

Comment: @user1314413, in that case try repairing / reinstalling VS once.